# Capture States on Account where the Account is doing business

Tags: relationships, schema

I am trying to establish relationship between Accounts of different Recordtypes

Account: CustomerID = BYR1 , RecordType = Buyer, Located IN = OH

Account: L1, RecordType  = Lender , Doing Business In =  OH, IN, MI, CO, NY, NJ

Account: L2,  RecordType = Lender,  Doing Business In =  IL, IN, MI, AL, AR, CA

Account: L3,  RecordType = Lender,  Doing Business In =  OH, IN, MI, AL, NY, CA

**Goal**: Show all Lenders doing business in the same state where the buyer is located

**Expected Result:** L1, L3

**What I have thought so far?**

- Create a new field 'Doing Business In' on RecordType Lender
- Select Data type of 'Doing Business In' such that the data is standardized  (text field would be a disaster state abbreviations may be incorrectly inputted or inputted twice etc)
- Should the data type 'Doing Business In' be Multiselect or is there a better option
- Pass the Buyer's Shipping State and get all records of 'recordtype:Lender' where 'Doing Business in' contains 'Buyers Shipping state'

**Question -** 
What would be the best way to capture states that the Lender is doing business in ?

Comment: Possible approach - You can store the State as Multiselect picklist and thats not available for lookup filter so you could try creating a formula checkbox field that checks the Multi--select Picklist for Buyer.ShippingState and then base lookup filter on that field.

INCLUDES(BusinessIn__c, Buyer.ShippingState__c)

Comment: @Mitesh  Thank you. In my use case I don't think a checkbox would work because there could be more than 1 Lender that is doing business in the same state as the Buyer. I need to show a list of lenders in that state as explained in the example in my question.

Comment: Checkbox was meant to indicate a bool value if you put the look up filter with this value as true then all the RT of lender with business in state where buyer is will be listed.

Comment: Ah i see ! Thanks! So i tried this- created a formula field , return type checkbox.  INCLUDES(multiselect_picklist_field, text_literal) . Is there a way to dynamically assign the 'text_literal' in my case Account.BillingState ?

Answer (score 1):

Since multiple values are captured for each lender please use a multi-select picklist. Also, please enable the 'Restrict picklist to the values defined in the value set' setting to make sure invalid data is not feed into this field (If you opt to use the global picklist as a value set, this setting will be checked by default).